# How to access Dispatcher when no reference to UI objects and Application.Current.Dispatcher is null?

Tags: wpf, mfc, dispatcher

I'm calling this from a non-UI thread (another thread than my WPF controls) :

```
public static FontFamily GetDefaultFontFamily()
{
    FontFamily fontFamily = null;

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
        new Action(
            delegate
            {
                fontFamily = new TextBlock().FontFamily;
            }));

    return fontFamily;
}
```

but `Application.Current` is `null` in my case (WPF objects hosted in MFC app)...

The only solution is to pass as a parameter a `DispatcherObject` instance, but this causes many modifications elsewhere, and makes it not a clean solution from the calling code.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you binding the FontFamily somewhere? Could you describe more of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Its primarely used to read information from the FontFamilly, but that besides the point...  The problem is that my method can be called outside of the WPF UI thread and in my case Application.Current is always null, so I need another way to find a valid Dipatcher...

Answer (score 1):

I got around the problem by making the class store a valid reference to a dispatcher the first time the class is used (made it a singleton too).

Not the best solution, but its the less worse...